# Add buttons to linked items on list group Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, itemgroup

I'm trying to implement a system and I need buttons inside linked group list. The problem is when I click on the button it opens the link of the linked item.
The code bellow is what I have on my system.

edit:
I need the full item to be clickable; excluding the buttons (Not using link just on the text).

```html
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
  
<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" href="https://www.fumep.edu.br/eep/" target="_blank">
    EEP
    <span class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <span class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS like this..

```
.list-group-item>.pull-right{
   cursor: default;
}
```

Add `onclick="return false;"` to the btn-group.

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/fi1MlO88ka)

Comment: I need the full area of the list item to be clicable excluding the buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full item clickable except buttons, you can try this with jQuery

```
$('.btn-group .btn').click(function(
    e.preventDefault();
});
```